# How do I encrypt password in AutoMapper 6?

Tags: c#, automapper

> Model name: UserModelInsert
>
> Entity name: User

```
CreateMap<UserModelInsert, User>()
.ForMember(
dest => dest.Password, 
src => src.MapFrom(?????????????????))
```

I have already ventured in various ways to try to get the correct result. I have already created the classes inheriting the interfaces IValueResolver, IMemberValueResolver and all that you can imagine, but I unfortunately could not solve this problem.

I just need something like this : `CreateMap<UserModelInsert, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.Password, src => src.MapFrom(s => StringUtils.Encrypt(s.Password)))` but it's not working

Comment: Why would AutoMapper have any responsibility for password encryption? AutoMapper is to map Models to DTOs/ViewModels and visa versa, the value of password is simply an encrypted string, other parts of your app must handle decrypting the Model/DTO/ViewModel with a password value that is encrypted

Comment: Because my project is a web api and I'm using generic classes. If I were not using the automapper I would do this on the controller when passing data from model to entity. If I do not do this I will have to inherit the method just because of an attribute. If it is to do this I prefer to remove the automapper

Comment: No of your becauses have anything to do what Automapper does. Automapper is for mapping Models, DTOs and ViewModels, it has nothing to do with your encryption, was not built to help with encryption and should not be hacked to handle encryption, you have design issues with your architecture it sounds like, sounds overly complex

Comment: I just need something like this :

CreateMap<UserModelInsert, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.Password, src => src.MapFrom(s => StringUtils.Encrypt(s.Password))) but it's not working

Comment: Your attempt matches mine and it works perfectly. You'll need to share the error details and better describe what is going wrong.

Comment: One more time, why do you think that Encryption should be intertwined with a entity/dto/model mapping or mapping configuration, it does not matter what issues you have with generics etc, you are hacking right now, bad hacking, giving some of your code too much responsibility, You are creating a AutoMapper configuration and expecting encryption to fire off in the same code line, monolithic big ball of mud apps is all you will end up with intentions like yours currently are

Answer (score 1):

OP:

> I just need something like this : `CreateMap<UserModelInsert, User>().ForMember(dest => dest.Password, src => src.MapFrom(s => StringUtils.Encrypt(s.Password)))` but it's not working

Just use AutoMapper's [Custom Type Converters](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) feature.

> Sometimes, you need to take complete control over the conversion of one type to another. This is typically when one type looks nothing like the other, a conversion function already exists, and you would like to go from a **"looser" type to a stronger type**, such as a source type of string to a destination type of Int32.

e.g. [courtesy](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Custom-type-converters) of AutoMap

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
      cfg.CreateMap<string, int>().ConvertUsing(s => Convert.ToInt32(s));
      cfg.CreateMap<string, DateTime>().ConvertUsing(new DateTimeTypeConverter());
      cfg.CreateMap<string, Type>().ConvertUsing<TypeTypeConverter>();
      cfg.CreateMap<Source, Destination>();
    });

public class DateTimeTypeConverter : ITypeConverter<string, DateTime>
{
    public DateTime Convert(string source, DateTime destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return System.Convert.ToDateTime(source);
    }
}
```

There is nothing stopping you from creating your own `MyPasswordConverter` that converts say from `string` to `SecureString`.

So taking your example you could produce something like:

```
public class MyPasswordConverter: ITypeConverter<string, SecureString>
{
    public SecureString Convert(string source, SecureString destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        return StringUtils.Encrypt(source);
    }
}
```

...assuming of course your `StringUtils.Encrypt` returns a `SecureString` (which it probably should).